# Does sublime have a color cucumber log file?

Tags: cucumber, sublimetext2

I am getting to the point where ANSICON does not help me when errors occur.

If I run an a complete smoke test and an error occurs on one of the first few features, it'll be out of ansicon's buffer, forcing me to rerun that specific feature.

My solution was to post it to a logfile...

```
cucumber --tags @smoke > cukelog.log
```

The only sadness here is that I lose color :(

This leads me to believe that sublime has an add on for color cucumber log files (not .feature)

Is there such an animal?

Comment: Try to use Cucumber formatters (e.g. --format html)

Comment: not bad..  creating a unique logfile extension and setting it to Cucumber Steps gets me color.  Just not green good, red bad.  Still much better.  Thanks!

Comment: OMG!! cucumber --format html > cukelog.html  I get it now.  You should make an answer so you get the points. This is so much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cucumber formatters to format Cucumber output.

I think flags `--format html --out output.html` will fit your needs. You can look at other formatters by typing `cucumber --help`

Comment: Thanks Andrey, this will make the readers of these test results very happy.